# Problema al hacer un echo con datos traidos desde una base de datos

Tags: php

Buen Dia
Estoy realizando una consulta desde php hacia sql server 2005, ya realice la conexion y puedo mostrar un resultado, pero si quiero agregar mas campos me devulve un error, estoy trabajando con WebMatrix y IIS Express,

```
include("header.php");
include("conexion.php");

$query=sqlsrv_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM ticket');

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo($row['usuario']
    echo($row['area']
    );
}
```

Mis campos son :

id_ticket, usuario, area, descripcion, fechaalta, fechafin, estado, solucion

Tengo el problema al poner el segundo campo, no se como terminar el primero, intente varias cosas pero me marca error, si solo dejo el campo usuario si lo muestra correctamente, si pongo el segundo ya marca error de sintaxis, en la documentación viene con un "."

Saludos!

Comment: todo el echo esta mal escrito.. o lo copiaste mal?

Comment: Por que dices que esta mal escrito? si pongo solo el primer campo si lo obtiene de la consulta y lo muestra

Comment: En el caso que lo estés ejecutando tal cual esta en la pregunta claramente te arroja error de sintaxis, deverias cerrar los parentesis y un punto y coma al final de las lineas del `echo` algo asi `echo($row['usuario']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate que estas armando mal la instruccion..

Por eso pregunte en mi comentario y kevin lo esciribio en el suyo.

```
 echo($row['usuario']);
 echo($row['area']);
```

Y lo que dices del `.` es porque el mismo se usa como simbolo de concatenacion en PHP.

Comment: Listo ya quedo resuelto, si habia pegado mal la sentencia, si inclui las ; finales pero me equivocaba en otra cosa, ya quedo funcionando, gracias